# Formatting numbers in Word table to display as currency using VBA

Tags: ms-access, ms-word, vba

I have VBA code that I run from MS Access. This code creates tables (of different sizes depending on the size of a query) in a Word document, and thereafter fills that Word document, with values from a query's columns using the Range.Text property. One of these columns is a currency value and another a percentage value. These values display correctly in Access itself.

Unfortunately values are outputted as eg. 987.6 and 1234.5, instead of 987.60 and 1234.50. As small as this is, it is a requirement and was hoping to find a solution and I am entirely unsure how to do this or if its even possible.
Discounts are displayed as 0.18 or 0.30 instead of 18 and 30

I can show my code for the export of the data if required however didn't see how it affected this part that I require.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the answer:

```
Format(123123, "Currency")
```

The currency would be from your local settings.

Edit: See the screenshot - open the immediate window, there you may write
`?Format(123123, "Currency")` and you will see the result. Screenshot attached.

[image]

Comment: Could you tell me more how to use this property? Do you use it with the text range. Sorry I am unfamiliar with it